# Lock bootstrap modal to bottom-right corner?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-modal

I'd like to lock a Bootstrap 3 modal to the bottom-right corner of the window, like this:

[image]

I have tried to move it using `top: x%; left: x%` CSS, but that completely breaks responsiveness. How do I lock it to the bottom right of the window, regardless of window size?

Thank you in advance.

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/eqhdqsyp/6

Comment: Have you tried this:  https://coolestguidesontheplanet.com/bootstrap/modal.php

Comment: Yep, when I tried to position it using `top:5%;left:50%;` it went off the screen.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

if you want to position it relative to the window, you want `position:fixed;` and if you want it to stay anchored right and bottom when the screen resizes left and top won't work, as you already noted so use `right` and `bottom` instead.

Bootstrap already styles this div like this:

```
@media (min-width: 768px)
.modal-dialog {
    width: 600px;
    margin: 30px auto;
}

.modal-dialog {
    position: relative;
    width: auto;
    margin: 10px;
}
```

so you'll need to override that with this:

```
.modal.in .modal-dialog {
    position:fixed;
    bottom:0px;
    right:0px;
    margin:0px;
}
```

http://codepen.io/ryantdecker/pen/ZOpQOX

Comment: This makes to modal pop back to the center on close when using a `fade` class for animations.

Comment: @binoculars, just change the CSS selector by removing the `.in`:  `.modal .modal-dialog { ... }` and it should work fine.

Comment: http://codepen.io/ryantdecker/pen/ZOpQOX page was deleted. Please update it

Comment: will try to get one back up, but in the meantime, the only thing unique compared to the OP jsfiddle is the css selector indicated in the answer, so it can easily be added to that fiddle to view the impact

Answer (score 1):

```
 .modal-class {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    right: 0;
 }
```

This should work.

Comment: This just makes it appear at the very top of the body, fixed and centered horizontally :(

Comment: I think your gonna have to show me your html code. You could try adding that CSS to the class .modal-dialog. Otherwise, show your html.

Comment: Yes, my CSS is working (add the css to .modal-dialog): https://jsfiddle.net/eqhdqsyp/8/

Comment: `position:absolute;` positions the element relative to it's nearest ancestor with a position other than static (the default). as a result this will only work if the modal is 1) a direct decendent of `body` and/or 2) there are no other ancestors of the modal that have `position`defined.  You're right on with the `bottom` and `right` instead of `left` and `top`, though.

Answer (score 1):

The basic concept from the link does seem to work. Here is a fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/d0nfh6kz/

```
#myModal1 {
  top:70%;
  left:27%;
  outline: none;
}

<!-- Button trigger modal -->
<a data-toggle="modal" href="#myModal1" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg">Launch demo modal</a>

<!-- Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="myModal1" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">×</button>
                <h4 class="modal-title">Modal title</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                ...
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
            </div>
        </div><!-- /.modal-content -->
    </div><!-- /.modal-dialog -->
</div><!-- /.modal -->
```